# Listview onclicklistener for only one item in android

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with one `TextView` and `ImageView`. I want only my ImageView to have a click listener. How can I implement this?

Comment: At least you should show us some code, what you have tried so far. This question does not lead to a direct answer.

Comment: Please post the code of ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

ViewHolder holder = null;

if (convertView == null) {

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = li.inflate(resource, parent, false);

    holder.imageview= (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);

    convertView.setTag(holder);

} else {

    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // handle click
    }
});

return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {

ImageView imageview;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use custom view for that customize your adapter.

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{   
String [] result;
Context context;
 int [] imageId;
  private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    result=prgmNameList;
    context=mainActivity;
    imageId=prgmImages;
     inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
             getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return result.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public class Holder
{
    TextView tv;
    ImageView img;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;       
         rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);
         holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         holder.img=(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);       
     holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
     holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);         
     holder.img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });   
    return rowView;
}
```

}

custom_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODo
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place an OnClickListener for the image view inside your custom Adapter.

**Example:**

```
viewHolder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    //Your code
  }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

ListView have lot of issues. You can use RecyclerView android l feature.